# Wrap that uses filesystem in C++

Tags: c++, file-system, c++17, wrapper

This is a wrap that queries the number of files and folder from a given directory, also list the folders and files into a vector. I have posted [another wrap in this discussion](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/234760/21571) that do the same things and following some really good suggestions I created another this time using `filesystem`.

The filesystem I used is [this implementation](https://github.com/gulrak/filesystem) I found on GitHub because the filesystem I tried to use in codeblocks kept throwing errors even the filesystem from GCC 9.2.

I didn't implement a cache mechanism because I don't know how to yet.

wrap.h

```
#ifndef WRAP_H_INCLUDED
#define WRAP_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <ghc/filesystem.hpp>

namespace dir
{
class Wrap
{
private:
    Wrap() {}

    enum mode {FOLDER = 0, FILE_};

    int number_of_entities_in_directory(std::string file_path, mode type_);
    std::vector<std::string> entities_in_directory(std::string file_path, mode type_);

    int number_of_entities_in_directory_recursively(std::string file_path, mode type_);
    std::vector<std::string> entities_in_directory_recursively(std::string file_path, mode type_);

public:
    static int number_of_files_in_directory(std::string file_path);
    static int number_of_folders_in_directory(std::string file_path);
    static void files_in_directory(std::string file_path, std::vector<std::string>& files);
    static void folders_in_directory(std::string file_path, std::vector<std::string>& folders);

    static int number_of_files_in_directory_recursively(std::string file_path);
    static int number_of_folders_in_directory_recursively(std::string file_path);
    static void files_in_directory_recursively(std::string file_path, std::vector<std::string>& files);
    static void folders_in_directory_recursively(std::string file_path, std::vector<std::string>& folders);

};
}

#endif // WRAP_H_INCLUDED
```

wrap.cpp

```
#include "wrap.h"

#include <ghc/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace ghc::filesystem;

using namespace std;

using namespace dir;

int Wrap::number_of_entities_in_directory(string file_path, mode type_)
{
    int counter = 0;

    string secure_file_path = file_path + "/";

    if ( ! exists(secure_file_path))
    {
        throw runtime_error("directory does not exist");
    }

    if(ghc::filesystem::is_empty(secure_file_path))
        return 0;

    directory_iterator it (secure_file_path);
    directory_iterator endit;

    while(it != endit)
    {
        if(type_ == FILE_ && is_regular_file(*it))
            ++counter;
        else if(type_ == FOLDER && is_directory(*it))
            ++counter;

        ++it;
    }

    return counter;
}

vector<string> Wrap::entities_in_directory(string file_path, mode type_)
{
    vector<string> entities;

    string secure_file_path = file_path + "/";

    if ( ! exists(secure_file_path))
    {
        throw runtime_error("directory does not exist");
    }

    directory_iterator it(secure_file_path);
    directory_iterator endit;

    if( ! ghc::filesystem::is_empty(secure_file_path))
        while (it != endit)
        {
            if(type_ == FILE_ && is_regular_file(*it))
                entities.push_back(it->path().filename());
            else if(type_ == FOLDER && is_directory(*it))
                entities.push_back(it->path().filename());

            ++it;
        }

    return entities;
}

int Wrap::number_of_entities_in_directory_recursively(string file_path,
        mode type_)
{
    int counter = 0;

    string secure_file_path = file_path + "/";

    if ( ! exists(secure_file_path))
    {
        throw runtime_error("directory does not exist");
    }

    if(ghc::filesystem::is_empty(secure_file_path))
        return 0;

    recursive_directory_iterator it (secure_file_path);
    recursive_directory_iterator endit;

    while(it != endit)
    {
        if(type_ == FILE_ && is_regular_file(*it))
            ++counter;
        else if(type_ == FOLDER && is_directory(*it))
            ++counter;

        ++it;
    }

    return counter;
}

vector<string> Wrap::entities_in_directory_recursively(string file_path,
        mode type_)
{
    vector<string> entities;

    string secure_file_path = file_path + "/";

    if ( ! exists(secure_file_path))
    {
        throw runtime_error("directory does not exist");
    }

    recursive_directory_iterator it(secure_file_path);
    recursive_directory_iterator endit;

    if( ! ghc::filesystem::is_empty(secure_file_path))
        while (it != endit)
        {
            if(type_ == FILE_ && is_regular_file(*it))
                entities.push_back(it->path().filename());
            else if(type_ == FOLDER && is_directory(*it))
                entities.push_back(it->path().filename());

            ++it;
        }

    return entities;
}

int Wrap::number_of_files_in_directory(string file_path)
{
    if(file_path.empty())
        return 0;

    Wrap dr;
    return dr.number_of_entities_in_directory(file_path, FILE_);
}

int Wrap::number_of_folders_in_directory(string file_path)
{
    if(file_path.empty())
        return 0;

    Wrap dr;
    return dr.number_of_entities_in_directory(file_path, FOLDER);;
}

void Wrap::files_in_directory(string file_path, vector<std::string>& files)
{
    if(file_path.empty())
        return;

    Wrap dr;
    files = dr.entities_in_directory(file_path, FILE_);
}

void Wrap::folders_in_directory(string file_path, vector<std::string>& folders)
{
    if(file_path.empty())
        return;

    Wrap dr;
    folders = dr.entities_in_directory(file_path, FOLDER);
}


int Wrap::number_of_files_in_directory_recursively(string file_path)
{
    if(file_path.empty())
        return 0;

    Wrap dr;
    return dr.number_of_entities_in_directory_recursively(file_path, FILE_);
}

int Wrap::number_of_folders_in_directory_recursively(string file_path)
{
    if(file_path.empty())
        return 0;

    Wrap dr;
    return dr.number_of_entities_in_directory_recursively(file_path, FOLDER);;
}

void Wrap::files_in_directory_recursively(string file_path,
        vector<std::string>& files)
{
    if(file_path.empty())
        return;

    Wrap dr;
    files = dr.entities_in_directory_recursively(file_path, FILE_);
}

void Wrap::folders_in_directory_recursively(string file_path,
        vector<std::string>& folders)
{
    if(file_path.empty())
        return;

    Wrap dr;
    folders = dr.entities_in_directory_recursively(file_path, FOLDER);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <wrap.h>

using namespace dir;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "D:/Music/";

    vector<string> vec;

    Wrap::folders_in_directory(path, vec);

    for(auto i : vec)
        cout << i << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I created the wrapper as a static library project and added the header file to the `include` folder, hence the line:

```
#include <wrap.h>
```

Comment: Can you provide some test code that exercises the wrap and demonstrates how to use it in code.

Comment: @pacmaninbw done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Avoid `using` too much `namespace`

You risk having identical names mapped onto each other. Either be more selective in what you are `using`, or create short aliases if you want to avoid typing long namespace names, like:

```
namespace fs = ghc::filesystem;
```

You already ran into this problem with `is_empty()`.

## Don't `#include` headers you don't need

In `wrap.h`, you `#include <ghc/filesystem.hpp>`, but nothing in that header file uses it. You should remove it, unless you plan to make the functions take `ghc::filesystem::path`'s as parameters instead of `std::string`s.

## Use `enum class` where possible

A regular `enum` is not very type-safe. Prefer an `enum class`.

## Be consistent in how you return results

Your private functions just return `std::vector<std::string>`, but the public functions take a reference to a `std::vector<std::string>`. Why is there a difference? Since the vector of strings is the result, just `return` it everywhere.

## Make the private member functions `static`

There is no reason for the private member functions not to be `static` in your class. But, then you'll realize that everything is `static`, which brings us to:

## There is no need to use a `class`

You are not storing any state in `class Wrap`, and all functions are or can be made `static`. So there is no reason to use a `class` here at all. You could move all the public member functions out of the class into `namespace dir`. The private member functions don't have to appear in `wrap.h` at all anymore.

## Why the underscores?

Why write `FILE_` and `type_`? Unless they are macros you should be able to declare those symbols in your own classes and namespaces without the trailing underscore.

## Avoid redundant tests for empty directories

There is no need to test for the directory being empty; your loops handle empty directories perfectly fine. You are adding unnecessary overhead in the common case where a directory is not empty, and if it is empty, your loops will just do nothing, so there is no performance penalty.

## Use range-for where appropriate

You can use range-for to iterate over a directory, just like an STL container. So for example, in `Wrap::number_of_entities_in_directory()`, you can write:

```
for(auto entity: directory_iterator(secure_file_path)) {
    if(type == mode::FILE && is_regular_file(entity))
        ++counter;
    else if(type == mode::FOLDER && is_directory(entity))
        ++counter;
}
```

## Consider using STL algorithms

Instead of writing your own loops, you could use STL algorithms. In fact, the whole function could be rewritten as:

```
#include <algorithm>
namespace fs = ghc::filesystem;
...
int Wrap::number_of_entities_in_directory(string file_path, mode type) {
    directory_iterator it(file_path);
    return std::count_if(fs::begin(it), fs::end(it), [type](const directory_entry &ent){
        return type == FOLDER ? is_directory(ent) : is_regular_file(ent);
    });
}
```

Comment: **[Be consistent in how you return results]**
Do you mean that instead of this: `void Wrap::files_in_directory(std::string file_path, vector<std::string>& files)` I should have it like this: `vector<std::string>Wrap::files_in_directory(std::string file_path)`

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Actually that was the first way I implemented that function but then I changed it into how it is now, I just prefer it like this

Comment: **[There is no need to use a `class`]** I wanted to put all the function definition into a cpp file and have the header with only declarations of those functions. Don't know at what extent it is worth though

Comment: That's unrelated to whether you use a class or not. You can still have the declarations in the header file outside a class, and have the definitions in a cpp file.

Comment: **[Why the underscores?]** I used `FILE_` to avoid any confusion to [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/FILE/)this. And the underscore in `type_` was random. Is there any convention for using underscores?

Comment: I tried that but when using the wrap I had `undefined references` (to those functions) errors, the lib file when using the wrap was added, so I thought it was not possible. Maybe I was wrong, I will try it again and check if I made any mistake

Comment: Ah, if you use `enum class` you don't have to worry about conflicting with stdio's `FILE`, as it will then be in its own namespace. I personally avoid leading and trailing underscores. Some code styles use a single underscore at the start or end to indicate that something is a member variable, or in C it's sometimes used to indicate that something is meant to be private. Note that some uses of underscores are [reserved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: **[Avoid redundant tests for empty directories]** I did that to avoid the performance penalty but thanks to you now I know there's none. I will change the code

Comment: **[Use `range-for` where appropriate]** I am new to `filesystem` so the `directory_iterator` was unknown to me until now. || 
**[Consider using STL algorithms]** wow, I see now that I am acturally not good with the STL algorithms, I will study it deeper and try to implement whenever I can. Answer upvoted, thanks for your review

Comment: You're welcome! If you find an answer useful, consider marking it as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can always change it later if someone else provides a better answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102774/discussion-between-hbatalha-and-g-sliepen).